# Добавить в билдер ресурс C#

Tags: c#

Сделал билдер на C#. В исходном коде, который должно комплитить есть потребность в ресурсе. Без него если создаю приложение - оно не работает.
Как добавить ресурс в билдер? Чтобы он строил выходной файл с этим ресурсом?
Пробовал добавлять параметры в ComplierOption - не помогло

```
Params.CompilerOptions += "\n/t:winexe \n/win32res:my.sql";
```

Comment: `Сделал билдер на C#.` Что, простите, сделал? Что вы обзываете билдером?

Answer (score 0):

Автор, будет здорово, если ты будешь более чётко формулировать мысли и описывать контекст задачи. Я могу лишь догадываться, что речь идёт о CodeDom. В этом случае пример с [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.compileroptions(v=vs.110).aspx) тебе в помощь.

```
if (Directory.Exists("Resources"))
{
    if (provider.Supports(GeneratorSupport.Resources))
    {
        // Set the embedded resource file of the assembly.
        // This is useful for culture-neutral resources,
        // or default (fallback) resources.
        cp.EmbeddedResources.Add("Resources\\Default.resources");

        // Set the linked resource reference files of the assembly.
        // These resources are included in separate assembly files,
        // typically localized for a specific language and culture.
        cp.LinkedResources.Add("Resources\\nb-no.resources");
    }
}
```

К слову, цивилизованный мир потихоньку уходит от CodeDom в сторону Roslyn. Если у тебя нет тонны наследственного кода, стоит идти в ногу со временем.